# Spark sql sum based on multiple cases

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark data frame to extract some statistic from my data. 
let's assume my data is like :

```
+----+------------+------+--------+-------+---------+
| id |    date    | type | player | level |  stage  |
+----+------------+------+--------+-------+---------+
|  1 | 2018-03-26 | XXX  | John   |     4 | stage_2 |
|  2 | 2018-03-26 | YYY  | Adam   |     1 | stage_1 |
|  3 | 2018-03-26 | ZZZ  | Sarah  |     6 | stage_3 |
|  4 | 2018-03-26 | XXX  | Bruce  |    12 | stage_2 |
|  5 | 2018-03-26 | YYY  | Sarah  |     6 | stage_1 |
|  6 | 2018-03-26 | ZZZ  | John   |     4 | stage_2 |
+----+------------+------+--------+-------+---------+
```

I want to count some data here, for example, when I want to count how many time I have something with type `XXX` each day I will do something like

```
dataframe.groupBy(date).agg(expr("sum(case when type = 'XXX'then 1 else 0 end) as XXX_Count"))
```

But I don't know what should I do for the more complicated use cases.

let's say I want to count how many time each player played at the highest stage he could, based on his/her level

I need to have this

When level between 1 and 3 stage should be 1
When level between 3 and 6 stage should be 2
When level between 6 and 12 stage should be 3
When level between 12 and 20 stage should be 4
When level > 20 stage should be 5

the result should be something like

```
+--------+-------+
| player | count |
+--------+-------+
| John   |     2 |
| Adam   |     1 |
| Sarah  |     1 |
| Bruce  |     0 |
+--------+-------+
```

let's say for John, his level is 4 so he should play on stage2 and based on the data he played 2 times on that stage, in Sarah's case she is level 6 so she should play on stage 3 but she only played on that stage one

Comment: You already got the stage column right ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala yes I do every column in the first table

Comment: And how do you count the count value ?

Comment: let's say for John, his level is 4 so he should play on stage2 and based on the data he played 2 times on that stage, in Sarah's case she is level 6 so she should play on stage 3 but she only played on that stage one

Comment: And what about the Bruce, how 0?

Comment: Because Bruce is level 12 and his highest should be 4 but he played at stage 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the max value as below expr

```
val level = col("level")
val expr = when((level >= 1 && level < 3), 1)
  .when((level >= 3 && level < 6), 2)
  .when((level >= 6 && level < 12), 3)
  .when((level >= 12 && level < 20), 4)
  .when(level > 20, 5)
  .otherwise(0)

df.withColumn("max", expr)
  .withColumn("stage", split($"stage", "_")(1))
  .withColumn("max", when($"stage" === $"max", 1).otherwise(0))
  .groupBy($"player").agg(sum($"max"))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+
|player|count|
+------+-----+
|Sarah |1    |
|John  |2    |
|Adam  |1    |
|Bruce |0    |
+------+-----+
```

Comment: The max is not working here because a player can play on lower stage not his/her max necessarily like Bruce.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA updated the answer please check, it should work now

Comment: I upvoted it, but let me see if it really work in my case then I am gonna accept it

Comment: is there any nice way to make the split part more mature, since my real data  I have satge_01 instead of stage_1 and my stage goes to 20. I have both stage_01 and stage_20 and so on

Comment: I can't think of better way, convert it to `int` after `split`

Comment: I am trying to apply it to my use-case, my data is different than what I posted here